# Where to store data I don't want in code?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, project, raspbian

I am making my first ever python project to be implemented on the raspberry pi. There is a bunch of information, such as database/table names, IDs, project directory path etc. that I have written down in my code. In the interest of flexibility, I don't want it there and would rather pull it out of some place that I can modify. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You can use SQLite: put this data into a database and then read it. It wouldn't be secure, though.

Comment: just write a configuration file something like a settings.py.

Then import it wherever you want like from settings import *

Comment: Or store your data in a json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a native ConfigParser library for reading .ini style files: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

**example.cfg**

```
[Section1]
db_username = "db_user"
db_password = "db_passwd"
```

**yourapp.py**

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.cfg')

print config.get('Section1', 'db_username')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly

Just write a configuration file something like a `settings.py`

Then import it wherever you want like from `settings import *`

### settings.py

`API_KEY = "asdh31134hasdhe812"`

`UNAME`  = "meUser"

### program.py

`import settings`

`print settings.API_KEY`
`>>asdh31134hasdhe812`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't improve project flexibility.